# $\{a_n\},\{b_n\}\subseteq\mathbb{C}$. If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(b_n-b_{n+1})$ and $\{a_n b_{n+1}\}$ converges, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I tried to use

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=M}^N a_nb_n=b_NA_N-b_NA_{m-1}-\displaystyle \sum_{n=M}^{N-1}(b_{n+1}-b_n)A_n, where A_k=\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^ka_n, and A_0=0$$.

But I get thinks like

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=M}^{N-1}(b_{n+1}-b_n)A_n=\displaystyle \sum_{n=M}^{N-1} \sum_{i=1}^n(b_{n+1}-b_n)a_i$$

I tried this to use the hipotesis but I don't know how to keep going, or if this is the way, any hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a counterexample
$$
a_n=1\quad,\quad b_n={1\over n}.
$$